# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on performSelectorInBackground

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector

I want to call this method in background,

```
-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSString* )Path AtIndex:(int)i
```

I am calling in this way but it crashes and shows `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_3:AtIndex:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.google.com",i, nil]];
```

How to call `downloadImage_3:` method in background ?

where i am doing mistake ?

Comment: What is the content of  `-(void)downloadImage_3:AtIndex:` method ?

Comment: What is 'i' here? You cant add int object to array. So it must be NSNumber. And in that case your method parameter must also be of NSNumber type.

Comment: `i` is `int` came from `for loop`

Comment: @Neha is there any other way in which i can pass multiple parameter without using `NSArray` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_3:AtIndex:) withObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://www.google.com",i, nil]  afterDelay:15.0];
```

Or try this

```
NSString* number    =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
NSArray* arrayValues    =   [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Merchant_SmallImage"],number, nil];
NSArray* arrayKeys      =   [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Path",@"Index",nil];
NSDictionary* dic   =   [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:arrayValues forKeys:arrayKeys];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_3:) withObject:dic];
```

Define downloadImage_3 function like this:

```
-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSDictionary *)dic 
{
   NSString *path = [dic valueForKey:@"Path"];
int i     = [[dic valueForKey:@"Index"] intValue];
  //Your code
}
```

Comment: snob-z:Sequence you passed for Dictionary is wrong. dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys will take object first and then key for that object

Comment: Shows EXC_BAD_ACCESS here `NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[msg_array objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Merchant_SmallImage"],@"Path",i,"Index", nil];`

Comment: is msg_array an array of dictionaries??

Comment: Actually your EXC_BAD_ACCESS occurs because you cant add an int to an array. so i hav converted it to nsstring and then i have passed the argument and in the -(void)downloadImage_3:(NSDictionary *)dic 
implementation i have casted it back to int.

Comment: else use nsmutable dictionary.                                 NSString* number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    NSMutableDictionary* dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [dic setValue:@"http://www.google.com" forKey:@"Path"];
    [dic setValue:number forKey:@"index"];
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_3:) withObject:dic];

    


-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic
{
    NSString *path = [dic valueForKey:@"Path"];
    int i     = [dic valueForKey:@"index"];

    //Your code
}

Answer (score 1):

You can not call parameterized function in `@selector`. Create NSDictionary and then pass that dictionary in `withObject:`

```
int atIndex = 2; // whatever index you want to pass
NSArray *arr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:obj1,obj2,nil];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:atIndex],@"AtIndex",arr,@"ImagesUrl", nil];
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(downloadImage_3:) withObject:dictionary];
```

Define `downloadImage_3` function like this:

```
-(void)downloadImage_3:(NSDictionary *)dic {
    // use dic and write your code
}
```

Comment: The values are not hardcoded like `1` and `2` which you are providing in `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys`. how to provide dynamic values

Comment: shows incompatible integer sending int to id here `NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:atIndex,@"AtIndex",arr,@"ImagesUrl", nil];`

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` for selectors that take multiple arguments. The suggestions other answers give sort of work, but they all assume you can manipulate the method you are calling, which is not always possible (or even a good idea for clarity).

I recommend using NSInvocation instead, as it allows multiple arguments, or alternatively using GCD to dispatch a block to a background queue (or any queue other than the main for that matter).

Here's an example usage of NSInvocation

```
NSMethodSignature *sig = [[self class] instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(downloadImage_3:AtIndex:)];
NSInvocation *inv = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sig];
[inv setTarget:self];
[inv setSelector:@selector(downloadImage_3:AtIndex:)];
[inv setArgument:(__bridge void *)@"http://www.google.com" atIndex:2];
NSUInteger i = 1;
[inv setArgument:&i atIndex:3];
[inv performSelectorInBackground:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil];
```

It's worth double checking, I wrote the code in the browser so I might've missed something the compiler will pick up.

As additional note, you should really re-think your method naming conventions, a much more standard way to name methods would have the method be named `-(void)downloadImage3:(NSString* )path atIndex:(int)i`. Notice how atIndex begins with lowercase and how there is no underscore (which just looks weird in the middle of a method name). Also it might be worth noting that using NSUInteger is preferred for the index, as NSArray in general works with NSUIntegers (both should work, but there are cases in which int might not suffice).

Comment: from where should i call `downloadImage3` method ?

Comment: NSInvocation does it for you, calling -invoke on NSInvocation will trigger the method you give it. In this case that would be the download method you described.